# R: Merge two tables by some predicate

Tags: r, data-manipulation, euclidean-distance

I have the following tables in R:

```
Sample             X        Y        Z  ...
Sample1            1.5      2.32     123.1     
Sample2            1.2      4.22     23.2     
Sample3            0.82     531      543.2    
.
.
.
```

-

```
Cluster      X        Y        Z  ...
1            1.5      2.32     123.1     
2            1.2      4.22     23.2     
3            0.82     531      543.2    
.
.
.
```

I would like to merge the tables like so

```
Sample      Cluster1  Cluster2
Sample1     d11       d12
Sample2     d21       d22
```

Where d_i_j is the distance of Sample i from Cluster j

Thanks for your help!

Comment: which distance do you want to use?
Also in your case the distance seems to be zero

Comment: A data frame of element wise euclidean distances could be made by `df = sqrt((sample-cluster)^2)`

Comment: @Cettt I'd like to use Euclidean Squared - and the data in my example is completely random. It's merely a demonstration of the desired process.